# Why ubuntu 20.04 cannot support mysql 5.7.33?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-20.04, mysql8, mysql5.7

Today I tried to update ubuntu from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.
with `do-release-uprade`

After upgrade completed, I tried to start mysql with `service mysql start`

The result is

`Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

And then I tried to check with `systemctl status mysql.service`

The result is

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-04-09 17:45:14 +07; 1min 52s ago
Process: 13824 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 09 17:45:14 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I cannot access to mysql anymore because service cannot start.

I do not want to lost any database. I do not have any backup, too.

Is backup `/var/lib/mysql` is enough? (Anything else that I should backup?)

I am very confuse. What should I do next?

1. Downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 Or
2. Find the way to reinstall mysql 5.7 for Ubuntu 20.04 Or
3. Try upgrade mysql to 8. (but I cannot start mysql service this time)

`Why ubuntu 20.04 cannot support mysql 5.7.33?`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, show us **MySQL** logs, not SystemD ones.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov log from `/var/log/mysql/error.log` the last line is 

`2021-04-09T09:24:45.435471Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete.` I think this is log before I upgrade to ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you tried to run mysqld by hand (`/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` or something like that, notice user who runs that must have access to data directory)? If it starts and you're able to connect with the mysql client, you can backup all databases and now you have a backup.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov mysqldump did not work because Server did not start but I am trying follow this but it is still not work  [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232558/install-mysql-5-7-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Was mysqld started successfully by hand (not by service manager)?

Comment: Show the output of `journalctl -u mysql`; also as previously mentioned, try to manually run mysql via something like `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` and include any output from it.

The best way to backup a database is with mysqldump, not by copying raw data on the disk. You should have taken a backup BEFORE upgrading - please always take a full backup in the future before performing work, in addition to having automated backups. You shouldn't lose any data, provided you cleanly shut down things and then did the upgrade. If you didn't, this could be a very big learning opportunity.

Comment: Which version were you running before?  What version is it trying to upgrade to?  (Your title is ambiguous.)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I make dicision to use mysql 8 that more compatible with ubuntu 20.04.

My step is

1. Uninstall everything that relate to mysql (except `/var/lib/mysql/`)

`apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`

`apt-get autoremove`

`apt-get autoclean`

2. Install Mysql 8 (Because I downgrade from 8 to 5.7 before that why I need to install again) https://www.fosstechnix.com/install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu/

`wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb`

`dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb`

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install mysql-server`

After that I choose **Use Legecy Authentication Method (Retain Mysql 5.x)**
And can start mysql normally again. I need to recheck everything form many project that will work well with mysql 8 or not.

I do not have any backup because this is just DB Local Test Server.

Thank you every one for help me.